# How do I pass a multiparameter string when doing a php request

Tags: php, android, mysql, web-services

If I want to get values from my php webservice which is connected to a mysql database with a multiple value string... how should I write it in the url for example.

What I want:

```
login?next=initial_page?email=(1,2,3)
```

if the webservice looks something like this:

```
select * from login where email in (('".$_GET["email"]."'))
```

is it possible or is there a better way, lets say I would send an array instead, how would I write the php webservice then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1)** If the values are `integer` then pass it like this way

```
login?next=initial_page&email=1,2,3
                       ^ // here it should be & not ?
```

And the query will be

```
$sql = "select * from login where email in (".$_GET["email"].")";
```

**Note :** Escape the string before embedding it in query to prevent `SQL injection`.

**2)** Another way is you can post the data in `JSON` format and at `PHP` end use `json_decode` to decode that data and use it in your query.

Answer (score 1):

You use the `&` character between each input like this:

```
login.php?next=initial_page&email=(1,2,3)
```

you can split it later like this if needed:

```
<?php
    // url= test.php?inputs=1,2,3
    $myVar=$_GET['inputs'];
    print_r($myVar);
    $myArray=explode(',', $myVar);
    print_r($myArray);
?>
```

Comment: Don't know how you get 1 upvote but your answer is totally senseless.

Comment: @YogeshSuthar Which part is senseless? I explained how to pass multiple parameters, and how to convert a single input like `1,2,3` into an array if he needs it.

Comment: OP wants that data to put inside the query, not to convert it to array. OP is saying that if he sends  array instead, how would he write the php webservice.

Comment: And how would he use strings inside a sql `in` statement without quotes? And what's easier to insert quotes into, random places in a string, or perhaps around elements of an array? And seriously, are you that annoyed that someone upvoted my answer and not yours? Just wow :)

Comment: I am not annoyed because of rep points. I said that you have given different answer rather than answering actual question.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

either it is numeric (1,2,3,...)

or (aaa@domain.com,bbb@domain.com,ccc@domain.com,...)

sql query except both ('1','2','3') and ('aaa@domain.com','bbb@domain.com','ccc@domain.com')

URL :

```
login?next=initial_page&email=1,2,3
or 
login?next=initial_page&email=aaa@domain.com,bbb@domain.com,ccc@domain.com
                       ^ //it should be &
```

get it in php file like

```
$email = $_GET['email'];

$email_array = explode(",",$email);

$email = implode("','",$email_array);

select * from login where email in ('$email')
```